# How to find bbox height and width for openlayer3 map

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm working on openlayer3 map, i had draw one bbox on map, now i want to find height and width of this bbox. Please let me know how to get this.
I had already tried `map.getPixelFromCordinate` but not able to get the size of it.

[image: map with bbox]

Yellow color border is bbox, for which i want height and width.

Please help me out.

Comment: Show the drawing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting heigh&width of bbox you can follow this way.

1) pass one by one coordinate to map.getPixelFromCordinate(), this will  returns pixels.

2) subtract two pixels for x coordinate as well as y. this will be height and width for that zoom level.